# Keep only the first directory/page after the address

Tags: javascript, url

I know this has been discussed a billion times but I have a specific question about taking the first page/folder from URL address in Javascript.

Let's say I navigate to my website like that:
http://www.user.com/grabMe/dontGrabme

I want to take only "grabMe", but please note, "grabMe" can change to something else everytime.
Though, it's definitely a pattern. I want to take the first "folder" after my domain, and take nothing else after that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the URL on the `/` and take the 3rd element.

```
var str = 'http://www.user.com/grabMe/dontGrabme'.split('/')[3];
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymbadqaz/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pathname` property of the location object:

```
location.pathname.split('/')[1]
```

If the current page URL is `http://www.user.com/grabMe/dontGrabme`, then `pathname` will be `/grabMe/dontGrabme` and splitting it by `/` give your an array, from which you take the second element.

Comment: Thank you so much! and thanks to who gave me points! the code is working. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myString = document.URL;
myRegexp = /^.*\/\/.*\/(.*)\/.*$/;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: split working good but I will check this out for learning! Thanks!

Comment: Even though the marked answer has a hardcoded URL, I agree that it has better readability.